# Movimento diagonal unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-5

sou iniciante no unity 5, estou tentando criar um jogo 2d, onde quero colocar movimentos diagonais após colisões, atualmente conseguir que meu objeto após colisão seja jogado para cima, mais não consigo de forma alguma fazer um movimento diagonal, minha matriz tem uma escala eixo y(0,6)e(0,-6) eixo x(6,0) e (-6,0), estou trabalhando com 2 objetos um retângulo e um circulo, o circulo fica dentro do retângulo, quando o circulo bate nas paredes do retângulo acontece a colisão e ação. Se alguém puder me ajuda fica grato.

Não tenho nenhum código para diagonal, somente para o pulo para cima.

Código:
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public Vector2 jump = new Vector2(0,300);
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Transform tmf;

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
    {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
   // tmf = GetComponent<Transform>();


    }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
    {
    clik();
    }

//Dectando colisão de objetos e adicionando ação.
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "piso")
        {


            jump.y += 100;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            rb.AddForce(jump);


    }
}



//Destruir objeto ao clickar
  void clik()
    {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
        Destroy(tmf);
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1):

Voce está zerando a velocidade com este comando : rb.velocity = Vector2.zero; isto deixa sem condições de ir pra frente ou pra tras . 
use  rb.velocity = new Vector2(direcao * speed, rbPlayer.velocity.y);
direcao= 1  Vai pra frente
direcao= -1 Vai pra trás
speed tem que ser maior que zero (0).

Comment: Desculpe  aí, não prestei atenção na data da postagem.

Answer (score 0):

Voce deve adicionar um valor para o jump.x tambem.
Ele esta com o valor 0 então o objeto só vai se mover em y e voce quer q ele se move em X tb.

Answer (score 0):

Você não consegue realizar o movimento na diagonal, pois você não esta adicionando valores nas direções da diagonal, ou seja nas direções X e Y juntas, você esta apenas adicionando em Y com o trecho `jump.y += 100;`, o que falta agora é adicionar valores também em X desta maneira `jump.x += 100` ou ainda

```
/*...*/
{
jump = new vector2(jump.x+100,jump.y+100);
rb.AddForce(jump);
}
/*...*/
```

Answer (score -3):

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
[HideInInspector]
public bool facingRight = true;         // Para determinar de que forma o jogador está enfrentando.
[HideInInspector]
public bool jump = false;               // Condição para saber se o jogador deve pular.

```
public float moveForce = 365f;          // Quantidade de força adicionada para mover o jogador para a esquerda e para a direita.
public float maxSpeed = 5f;             // O mais rápido que o jogador pode viajar no eixo x.
public AudioClip[] jumpClips;           // Conjunto de clipes para quando o jogador salta.
public float jumpForce = 1000f;         // Quantidade de força adicionada quando o jogador salta.
public AudioClip[] taunts;              // Conjunto de clipes para quando o jogador se toca.
public float tauntProbability = 50f;    // Possa uma provocação.
public float tauntDelay = 1f;           // Atrasar para quando a provocação deve acontecer.


private int tauntIndex;                 // O índice da matriz de provocações indicando a provocação mais recente.
private Transform groundCheck;          // Uma marcação de posição onde verificar se o jogador está aterrado.
private bool grounded = false;          // Independentemente de o jogador estar ou não ligado.
private Animator anim;                  // Referência ao componente do animador do jogador.

void Awake()
{
    // Configurando referências.
    groundCheck = transform.Find("groundCheck");
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}


void Update()
{
    //O jogador está aterrado se um linecast na posição groundcheck atinja qualquer coisa na camada terrestre.
    grounded = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));

    // Se o botão de salto for pressionado e o jogador estiver aterrado, o jogador deve pular.
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
        jump = true;
}


void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Cache a entrada horizontal.
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    // O parâmetro Speed animator é definido como o valor absoluto da entrada horizontal.
    anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(h));

    // Se o jogador estiver mudando de direção (h tem um sinal diferente para velocity.x) ou ainda não alcançou o MaxSpeed ...
    if (h * GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < maxSpeed)
        //  ... adicione uma força ao jogador.
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.right * h * moveForce);

    // Se a velocidade horizontal do jogador for maior do que o maxSpeed ...
    if (Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x) > maxSpeed)
        // ... ajuste a velocidade do jogador para o maxSpeed no eixo x.
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x) * maxSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

    // Se a entrada estiver movendo o jogador para a direita e o jogador estiver virado para a esquerda ...
    if (h > 0 && !facingRight)
        // ... flip the player.
        Flip();
    // Caso contrário, se a entrada estiver movendo o jogador para a esquerda e o jogador estiver virado para a direita ...
    else if (h < 0 && facingRight)
        // ... vire o jogador.
        Flip();

    // If the player should jump...
    if(jump)
    {
        // Set the Jump animator trigger parameter.
        anim.SetTrigger("Jump");

        // Play a random jump audio clip.
        int i = Random.Range(0, jumpClips.Length);
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(jumpClips[i], transform.position);

        // Add a vertical force to the player.
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));

        // Make sure the player can't jump again until the jump conditions from Update are satisfied.
        jump = false;
    }
}


void Flip ()
{
    // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
    facingRight = !facingRight;

    // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}


public IEnumerator Taunt()
{
    // Check the random chance of taunting.
    float tauntChance = Random.Range(0f, 100f);
    if(tauntChance > tauntProbability)
    {
        // Wait for tauntDelay number of seconds.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(tauntDelay);

        // If there is no clip currently playing.
        if(!GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying)
        {
            // Choose a random, but different taunt.
            tauntIndex = TauntRandom();

            // Play the new taunt.
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = taunts[tauntIndex];
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }
    }
}


int TauntRandom()
{
    // Choose a random index of the taunts array.
    int i = Random.Range(0, taunts.Length);

    // If it's the same as the previous taunt...
    if(i == tauntIndex)
        // ... try another random taunt.
        return TauntRandom();
    else
        // Otherwise return this index.
        return i;
}
```

}

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?